# .htaccess - how to redirect http:// to https:// for specific url

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect from http to https for specific url.
For example, i need to have https for:

```
mysite.com/page1
```

I don't need https for:

```
mysite.com/page2,  mysite.com/page3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use redirect. It will redirect with to https page with code 301

```
Redirect 301 /page1 https://www.domaincom/page1
```

Comment: Redirect 301 /page1 https://domaincom/page1

This is working, but I have confict with another rule

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

which is rewriting https://domaincom/page1 into http://domaincom/page1

How to get working of both rules?

Comment: Edited my answer. In short add `www.` before `domain.com`. It will automatically redirect it to the correct site with `www`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page1[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect 301 /page1 https://domaincom/page1
```

This is working, but I have confict with another rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which is rewriting https://domaincom/page1 into http://domaincom/page1

How to get working of both rules?